# Couchbase problem with PHP SDK 4.x on Windows 10 - no response

Tags: sdk, couchbase

problem with PHP SDK 4.1.4 on Windows 10 to access a local Couchbase Server 7.1.2:
I compiled the SDK on Windows 10, with Visual Studio Community 2022 v17.4.3 (MSVC v14.3) without errors, build is done, and when i call phpinfo(), the couchbase module is listed with v4.1.4 and enabled. The PHP SDK is installed with composer too.

But, when i run the PHP script, it died without Exception or error in PHP log if the PHP script tried to call
$getResult = $collection->get("20230108T143220_16");
When I try to call $bucket->ping() or $bucket->diagnostics(): Same problem: no error message, PHP script ends.
The same PHP script is running fine on Ubuntu Server.

I followed this instructions:

https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-php-client/blob/4.0.0/WINDOWS.md

https://docs.couchbase.com/php-sdk/current/hello-world/start-using-sdk.html

Any tips or hint, what's the problem could be?

this is the part in PHP script:

```
require_once '../../vendor/autoload.php';
use \Couchbase as CB;
...
           $connectionString = "couchbase://127.0.0.1";
           $clusterOptions = new CB\ClusterOptions();            
           $clusterOptions->credentials("myuser", "mypassword");

           $cluster = new CB\Cluster($connectionString, $clusterOptions);
           $bucket = $cluster->bucket($bucketname);
           $scope = $bucket->scope("_default");
           $collection = $scope->collection("_default");

           try {
               $getResult = $collection->get("20230108T143220_16");
           } catch (CB\TimeoutException $e) {
               $fp=fopen($this->log_file,"a+");
               fwrite($fp,"error: ".print_r($e,true)."\n");
               fclose($fp);                            
           }    catch (CB\BaseException $e) {
               $fp=fopen($this->log_file,"a+");
               fwrite($fp,"error: ".print_r($e,true)."\n");
               fclose($fp);                
           }
```

This is the log:

```
[04-Jun-2023 14:22:50 Europe/Berlin] {"level":"debug","message":"don't cleanup idle connections. max_persistent=-1, num_persistent=0","source":{"file":"C:\\php-sdk\\php-dev\\vs17\\x64\\modules\\couchbase-php-client\\src\\wrapper\\persistent_connections_cache.cxx","func":"couchbase::php::create_persistent_connection","line":107},"thread_id":9344,"time":"2023-06-04 14:22:50.296080"}
[04-Jun-2023 14:22:50 Europe/Berlin] {"level":"debug","message":"Found DNS Servers: [192.168.0.1], using nameserver: 192.168.0.1","source":{"file":"C:\\php-sdk\\php-dev\\vs17\\x64\\modules\\couchbase-php-client\\src\\deps\\couchbase-cxx-client\\core\\io\\dns_config.cxx","func":"couchbase::core::io::dns::load_resolv_conf","line":90},"thread_id":9344,"time":"2023-06-04 14:22:50.356152"}
[04-Jun-2023 14:22:50 Europe/Berlin] {"level":"debug","message":"[707e13-036e-9341-153b-a422467ed87e98/c934e8-2c8d-5d4c-467d-4cf90be33cca83/plain/-] <127.0.0.1:11210> attempt to establish MCBP connection","source":{"file":"C:\\php-sdk\\php-dev\\vs17\\x64\\modules\\couchbase-php-client\\src\\deps\\couchbase-cxx-client\\core\\io\\mcbp_session.cxx","func":"couchbase::core::io::mcbp_session_impl::initiate_bootstrap","line":788},"thread_id":9344,"time":"2023-06-04 14:22:50.404917"}
[04-Jun-2023 14:22:50 Europe/Berlin] {"level":"debug","message":"[707e13-036e-9341-153b-a422467ed87e98/c934e8-2c8d-5d4c-467d-4cf90be33cca83/plain/-] <127.0.0.1:11210> connecting to 127.0.0.1:11210, timeout=2000ms","source":{"file":"C:\\php-sdk\\php-dev\\vs17\\x64\\modules\\couchbase-php-client\\src\\deps\\couchbase-cxx-client\\core\\io\\mcbp_session.cxx","func":"couchbase::core::io::mcbp_session_impl::do_connect","line":1286},"thread_id":12944,"time":"2023-06-04 14:22:50.406755"}
[04-Jun-2023 14:22:50 Europe/Berlin] {"level":"debug","message":"[707e13-036e-9341-153b-a422467ed87e98/c934e8-2c8d-5d4c-467d-4cf90be33cca83/plain/-] <127.0.0.1:11210> connected to 127.0.0.1:11210","source":{"file":"C:\\php-sdk\\php-dev\\vs17\\x64\\modules\\couchbase-php-client\\src\\deps\\couchbase-cxx-client\\core\\io\\mcbp_session.cxx","func":"couchbase::core::io::mcbp_session_impl::on_connect","line":1334},"thread_id":12944,"time":"2023-06-04 14:22:50.410221"}
[04-Jun-2023 14:22:50 Europe/Berlin] {"level":"debug","message":"[707e13-036e-9341-153b-a422467ed87e98/c934e8-2c8d-5d4c-467d-4cf90be33cca83/plain/-] <127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:11210> user_agent={\"a\":\"cxx/1.0.0/adc416d;Windows/AMD64;php_sdk/4.1.4/c4a662ad;ssl/30000070;php/8.1.13-dev/n\",\"i\":\"707e13-036e-9341-153b-a422467ed87e98/c934e8-2c8d-5d4c-467d-4cf90be33cca83\"}, requested_features=[tcp_nodelay, xattr, xerror, select_bucket, json, duplex, alt_request_support, tracing, sync_replication, vattr, collections, subdoc_create_as_deleted, preserve_ttl, unordered_execution, snappy, mutation_seqno]","source":{"file":"C:\\php-sdk\\php-dev\\vs17\\x64\\modules\\couchbase-php-client\\src\\deps\\couchbase-cxx-client\\core\\io\\mcbp_session.cxx","func":"couchbase::core::io::mcbp_session_impl::bootstrap_handler::bootstrap_handler","line":151},"thread_id":12944,"time":"2023-06-04 14:22:50.414405"}
[04-Jun-2023 14:22:50 Europe/Berlin] {"level":"trace","message":"[707e13-036e-9341-153b-a422467ed87e98/c934e8-2c8d-5d4c-467d-4cf90be33cca83/plain/-] <127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:11210> MCBP send, opaque=1,  80 1f 00 ac 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 cc 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00","source":{"file":"C:\\php-sdk\\php-dev\\vs17\\x64\\modules\\couchbase-php-client\\src\\deps\\couchbase-cxx-client\\core\\io\\mcbp_session.cxx","func":"couchbase::core::io::mcbp_session_impl::write","line":874},"thread_id":12944,"time":"2023-06-04 14:22:50.414639"}
[04-Jun-2023 14:22:50 Europe/Berlin] {"level":"trace","message":"[707e13-036e-9341-153b-a422467ed87e98/c934e8-2c8d-5d4c-467d-4cf90be33cca83/plain/-] <127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:11210> MCBP send, opaque=2,  80 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00","source":{"file":"C:\\php-sdk\\php-dev\\vs17\\x64\\modules\\couchbase-php-client\\src\\deps\\couchbase-cxx-client\\core\\io\\mcbp_session.cxx","func":"couchbase::core::io::mcbp_session_impl::write","line":874},"thread_id":12944,"time":"2023-06-04 14:22:50.414705"}
[04-Jun-2023 14:22:50 Europe/Berlin] {"level":"trace","message":"[707e13-036e-9341-153b-a422467ed87e98/c934e8-2c8d-5d4c-467d-4cf90be33cca83/plain/-] <127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:11210> MCBP send, opaque=3,  80 21 00 0c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 5a 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00","source":{"file":"C:\\php-sdk\\php-dev\\vs17\\x64\\modules\\couchbase-php-client\\src\\deps\\couchbase-cxx-client\\core\\io\\mcbp_session.cxx","func":"couchbase::core::io::mcbp_session_impl::write","line":874},"thread_id":12944,"time":"2023-06-04 14:22:50.414847"}
[04-Jun-2023 14:22:50 Europe/Berlin] {"level":"trace","message":"[707e13-036e-9341-153b-a422467ed87e98/c934e8-2c8d-5d4c-467d-4cf90be33cca83/plain/-] <127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:11210> MCBP recv, opaque=1,  81 1f 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 20 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00","source":{"file":"C:\\php-sdk\\php-dev\\vs17\\x64\\modules\\couchbase-php-client\\src\\deps\\couchbase-cxx-client\\core\\io\\mcbp_session.cxx","func":"couchbase::core::io::mcbp_session_impl::do_read::<lambda_031a81a04307852cd14ea860ca23ba23>::operator ()","line":1401},"thread_id":12944,"time":"2023-06-04 14:22:50.418055"}
[04-Jun-2023 14:22:50 Europe/Berlin] {"level":"debug","message":"[707e13-036e-9341-153b-a422467ed87e98/c934e8-2c8d-5d4c-467d-4cf90be33cca83/plain/-] <127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:11210> supported_features=[tcp_nodelay, mutation_seqno, xattr, xerror, select_bucket, snappy, json, duplex, unordered_execution, tracing, alt_request_support, sync_replication, collections, preserve_ttl, vattr, subdoc_create_as_deleted]","source":{"file":"C:\\php-sdk\\php-dev\\vs17\\x64\\modules\\couchbase-php-client\\src\\deps\\couchbase-cxx-client\\core\\io\\mcbp_session.cxx","func":"couchbase::core::io::mcbp_session_impl::bootstrap_handler::handle","line":239},"thread_id":12944,"time":"2023-06-04 14:22:50.418292"}
[04-Jun-2023 14:22:50 Europe/Berlin] {"level":"trace","message":"[707e13-036e-9341-153b-a422467ed87e98/c934e8-2c8d-5d4c-467d-4cf90be33cca83/plain/-] <127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:11210> MCBP recv, opaque=2,  18 20 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 2d 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00","source":{"file":"C:\\php-sdk\\php-dev\\vs17\\x64\\modules\\couchbase-php-client\\src\\deps\\couchbase-cxx-client\\core\\io\\mcbp_session.cxx","func":"couchbase::core::io::mcbp_session_impl::do_read::<lambda_031a81a04307852cd14ea860ca23ba23>::operator ()","line":1401},"thread_id":12944,"time":"2023-06-04 14:22:50.418349"}
[04-Jun-2023 14:22:50 Europe/Berlin] {"level":"trace","message":"[707e13-036e-9341-153b-a422467ed87e98/c934e8-2c8d-5d4c-467d-4cf90be33cca83/plain/-] <127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:11210> MCBP recv, opaque=3,  18 21 03 00 00 00 00 21 00 00 00 b0 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00","source":{"file":"C:\\php-sdk\\php-dev\\vs17\\x64\\modules\\couchbase-php-client\\src\\deps\\couchbase-cxx-client\\core\\io\\mcbp_session.cxx","func":"couchbase::core::io::mcbp_session_impl::do_read::<lambda_031a81a04307852cd14ea860ca23ba23>::operator ()","line":1401},"thread_id":12944,"time":"2023-06-04 14:22:50.419272"}
[04-Jun-2023 14:22:50 Europe/Berlin] {"level":"trace","message":"decoding attribute list [r=0x5f 0xfffffff0 0x37 0x04 0xffffffcf 0x45 0x0c 0xffffff8d6828212c8220761a,s=X7pqZrmv5K+w793k96g3ruXftkO5WtChGD9AJ0h6v6laVc6s7n6ncSjRlV/cbz1Mpar1R2Y8IufYXAViAOtfKg==,i=4000]","source":{"file":"C:\\php-sdk\\php-dev\\vs17\\x64\\modules\\couchbase-php-client\\src\\deps\\couchbase-cxx-client\\core\\sasl\\scram-sha\\scram-sha.cc","func":"couchbase::core::sasl::mechanism::scram::decodeAttributeList","line":52},"thread_id":12944,"time":"2023-06-04 14:22:50.419369"}
[04-Jun-2023 14:22:50 Europe/Berlin] {"level":"trace","message":"[707e13-036e-9341-153b-a422467ed87e98/c934e8-2c8d-5d4c-467d-4cf90be33cca83/plain/-] <127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:11210> MCBP send, opaque=4,  80 22 00 0c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 b9 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00","source":{"file":"C:\\php-sdk\\php-dev\\vs17\\x64\\modules\\couchbase-php-client\\src\\deps\\couchbase-cxx-client\\core\\io\\mcbp_session.cxx","func":"couchbase::core::io::mcbp_session_impl::write","line":874},"thread_id":12944,"time":"2023-06-04 14:22:50.479348"}
[04-Jun-2023 14:22:50 Europe/Berlin] {"level":"trace","message":"[707e13-036e-9341-153b-a422467ed87e98/c934e8-2c8d-5d4c-467d-4cf90be33cca83/plain/-] <127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:11210> MCBP recv, opaque=4,  18 22 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 5d 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00","source":{"file":"C:\\php-sdk\\php-dev\\vs17\\x64\\modules\\couchbase-php-client\\src\\deps\\couchbase-cxx-client\\core\\io\\mcbp_session.cxx","func":"couchbase::core::io::mcbp_session_impl::do_read::<lambda_031a81a04307852cd14ea860ca23ba23>::operator ()","line":1401},"thread_id":12944,"time":"2023-06-04 14:22:50.483906"}
[04-Jun-2023 14:22:50 Europe/Berlin] {"level":"trace","message":"[707e13-036e-9341-153b-a422467ed87e98/c934e8-2c8d-5d4c-467d-4cf90be33cca83/plain/-] <127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:11210> MCBP send, opaque=5,  80 fe 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00","source":{"file":"C:\\php-sdk\\php-dev\\vs17\\x64\\modules\\couchbase-php-client\\src\\deps\\couchbase-cxx-client\\core\\io\\mcbp_session.cxx","func":"couchbase::core::io::mcbp_session_impl::write","line":874},"thread_id":12944,"time":"2023-06-04 14:22:50.484070"}
[04-Jun-2023 14:22:50 Europe/Berlin] {"level":"trace","message":"[707e13-036e-9341-153b-a422467ed87e98/c934e8-2c8d-5d4c-467d-4cf90be33cca83/plain/-] <127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:11210> MCBP send, opaque=6,  80 b5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00","source":{"file":"C:\\php-sdk\\php-dev\\vs17\\x64\\modules\\couchbase-php-client\\src\\deps\\couchbase-cxx-client\\core\\io\\mcbp_session.cxx","func":"couchbase::core::io::mcbp_session_impl::write","line":874},"thread_id":12944,"time":"2023-06-04 14:22:50.484085"}
[04-Jun-2023 14:22:50 Europe/Berlin] {"level":"trace","message":"[707e13-036e-9341-153b-a422467ed87e98/c934e8-2c8d-5d4c-467d-4cf90be33cca83/plain/-] <127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:11210> MCBP recv, opaque=5,  18 fe 03 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 1f 21 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00","source":{"file":"C:\\php-sdk\\php-dev\\vs17\\x64\\modules\\couchbase-php-client\\src\\deps\\couchbase-cxx-client\\core\\io\\mcbp_session.cxx","func":"couchbase::core::io::mcbp_session_impl::do_read::<lambda_031a81a04307852cd14ea860ca23ba23>::operator ()","line":1401},"thread_id":12944,"time":"2023-06-04 14:22:50.485276"}
[04-Jun-2023 14:22:50 Europe/Berlin] {"level":"trace","message":"[707e13-036e-9341-153b-a422467ed87e98/c934e8-2c8d-5d4c-467d-4cf90be33cca83/plain/-] <127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:11210> MCBP recv, opaque=6,  18 b5 03 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 02 86 00 00 00 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00","source":{"file":"C:\\php-sdk\\php-dev\\vs17\\x64\\modules\\couchbase-php-client\\src\\deps\\couchbase-cxx-client\\core\\io\\mcbp_session.cxx","func":"couchbase::core::io::mcbp_session_impl::do_read::<lambda_031a81a04307852cd14ea860ca23ba23>::operator ()","line":1401},"thread_id":12944,"time":"2023-06-04 14:22:50.490536"}
[04-Jun-2023 14:22:50 Europe/Berlin] {"level":"debug","message":"[707e13-036e-9341-153b-a422467ed87e98/c934e8-2c8d-5d4c-467d-4cf90be33cca83/plain/-] <127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:11210> detected network is \"default\"","source":{"file":"C:\\php-sdk\\php-dev\\vs17\\x64\\modules\\couchbase-php-client\\src\\deps\\couchbase-cxx-client\\core/cluster.hxx","func":"couchbase::core::cluster::do_open::<lambda_e985158958b89eddab7854f96b087e4f>::operator ()","line":460},"thread_id":12944,"time":"2023-06-04 14:22:50.491556"}
[04-Jun-2023 14:22:50 Europe/Berlin] {"level":"trace","message":"[707e13-036e-9341-153b-a422467ed87e98/c934e8-2c8d-5d4c-467d-4cf90be33cca83/plain/-] <127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:11210> MCBP send, opaque=7,  80 b5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00","source":{"file":"C:\\php-sdk\\php-dev\\vs17\\x64\\modules\\couchbase-php-client\\src\\deps\\couchbase-cxx-client\\core\\io\\mcbp_session.cxx","func":"couchbase::core::io::mcbp_session_impl::write","line":874},"thread_id":12944,"time":"2023-06-04 14:22:50.491870"}
[04-Jun-2023 14:22:50 Europe/Berlin] {"level":"trace","message":"[707e13-036e-9341-153b-a422467ed87e98/c934e8-2c8d-5d4c-467d-4cf90be33cca83/plain/-] <127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:11210> MCBP recv, opaque=7,  18 b5 03 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 02 86 00 00 00 07 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00","source":{"file":"C:\\php-sdk\\php-dev\\vs17\\x64\\modules\\couchbase-php-client\\src\\deps\\couchbase-cxx-client\\core\\io\\mcbp_session.cxx","func":"couchbase::core::io::mcbp_session_impl::do_read::<lambda_031a81a04307852cd14ea860ca23ba23>::operator ()","line":1401},"thread_id":12944,"time":"2023-06-04 14:22:50.492740"}
[04-Jun-2023 14:22:50 Europe/Berlin] {"level":"debug","message":"persistent connection miss, created new connection: handle=0x14335f81760, connection_hash=f8854b3e4f42c5f2dd5f6844f8f60842d7892766418000561eee308b17559ee9, connection_string=\"couchbase://127.0.0.1\", expires_at=\"2023-06-04 14:22:50\" (0[1/10000000]s), destructor_id=19, num_persistent=1","source":{"file":"C:\\php-sdk\\php-dev\\vs17\\x64\\modules\\couchbase-php-client\\src\\wrapper\\persistent_connections_cache.cxx","func":"couchbase::php::create_persistent_connection","line":145},"thread_id":9344,"time":"2023-06-04 14:22:50.492899"}
[04-Jun-2023 14:22:50 Europe/Berlin] {"level":"trace","message":"[707e13-036e-9341-153b-a422467ed87e98/c934e8-2c8d-5d4c-467d-4cf90be33cca83/plain/-] <127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:11210> received a configuration with identical revision (rev=1:564), ignoring","source":{"file":"C:\\php-sdk\\php-dev\\vs17\\x64\\modules\\couchbase-php-client\\src\\deps\\couchbase-cxx-client\\core\\io\\mcbp_session.cxx","func":"couchbase::core::io::mcbp_session_impl::update_configuration","line":1111},"thread_id":12944,"time":"2023-06-04 14:22:50.493285"}
[04-Jun-2023 14:22:50 Europe/Berlin] {"level":"debug","message":"[707e13-036e-9341-153b-a422467ed87e98/f208f6-202c-604d-c7f5-3c008c037d347f/plain/playerlog] <127.0.0.1:11210> attempt to establish MCBP connection","source":{"file":"C:\\php-sdk\\php-dev\\vs17\\x64\\modules\\couchbase-php-client\\src\\deps\\couchbase-cxx-client\\core\\io\\mcbp_session.cxx","func":"couchbase::core::io::mcbp_session_impl::initiate_bootstrap","line":788},"thread_id":9344,"time":"2023-06-04 14:22:50.543187"}
[04-Jun-2023 14:22:50 Europe/Berlin] {"level":"debug","message":"[707e13-036e-9341-153b-a422467ed87e98/f208f6-202c-604d-c7f5-3c008c037d347f/plain/playerlog] <127.0.0.1:11210> connecting to 127.0.0.1:11210, timeout=2000ms","source":{"file":"C:\\php-sdk\\php-dev\\vs17\\x64\\modules\\couchbase-php-client\\src\\deps\\couchbase-cxx-client\\core\\io\\mcbp_session.cxx","func":"couchbase::core::io::mcbp_session_impl::do_connect","line":1286},"thread_id":12944,"time":"2023-06-04 14:22:50.543533"}
[04-Jun-2023 14:22:50 Europe/Berlin] {"level":"debug","message":"[707e13-036e-9341-153b-a422467ed87e98/f208f6-202c-604d-c7f5-3c008c037d347f/plain/playerlog] <127.0.0.1:11210> connected to 127.0.0.1:11210","source":{"file":"C:\\php-sdk\\php-dev\\vs17\\x64\\modules\\couchbase-php-client\\src\\deps\\couchbase-cxx-client\\core\\io\\mcbp_session.cxx","func":"couchbase::core::io::mcbp_session_impl::on_connect","line":1334},"thread_id":12944,"time":"2023-06-04 14:22:50.545848"}
[04-Jun-2023 14:22:50 Europe/Berlin] {"level":"debug","message":"[707e13-036e-9341-153b-a422467ed87e98/f208f6-202c-604d-c7f5-3c008c037d347f/plain/playerlog] <127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:11210> user_agent={\"a\":\"cxx/1.0.0/adc416d;Windows/AMD64;php_sdk/4.1.4/c4a662ad;ssl/30000070;php/8.1.13-dev/n\",\"i\":\"707e13-036e-9341-153b-a422467ed87e98/f208f6-202c-604d-c7f5-3c008c037d347f\"}, requested_features=[tcp_nodelay, xattr, xerror, select_bucket, json, duplex, alt_request_support, tracing, sync_replication, vattr, collections, subdoc_create_as_deleted, preserve_ttl, unordered_execution, snappy, mutation_seqno]","source":{"file":"C:\\php-sdk\\php-dev\\vs17\\x64\\modules\\couchbase-php-client\\src\\deps\\couchbase-cxx-client\\core\\io\\mcbp_session.cxx","func":"couchbase::core::io::mcbp_session_impl::bootstrap_handler::bootstrap_handler","line":151},"thread_id":12944,"time":"2023-06-04 14:22:50.546430"}
[04-Jun-2023 14:22:50 Europe/Berlin] {"level":"trace","message":"[707e13-036e-9341-153b-a422467ed87e98/f208f6-202c-604d-c7f5-3c008c037d347f/plain/playerlog] <127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:11210> MCBP send, opaque=1,  80 1f 00 ac 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 cc 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00","source":{"file":"C:\\php-sdk\\php-dev\\vs17\\x64\\modules\\couchbase-php-client\\src\\deps\\couchbase-cxx-client\\core\\io\\mcbp_session.cxx","func":"couchbase::core::io::mcbp_session_impl::write","line":874},"thread_id":12944,"time":"2023-06-04 14:22:50.546473"}
[04-Jun-2023 14:22:50 Europe/Berlin] {"level":"trace","message":"[707e13-036e-9341-153b-a422467ed87e98/f208f6-202c-604d-c7f5-3c008c037d347f/plain/playerlog] <127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:11210> MCBP send, opaque=2,  80 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00","source":{"file":"C:\\php-sdk\\php-dev\\vs17\\x64\\modules\\couchbase-php-client\\src\\deps\\couchbase-cxx-client\\core\\io\\mcbp_session.cxx","func":"couchbase::core::io::mcbp_session_impl::write","line":874},"thread_id":12944,"time":"2023-06-04 14:22:50.546497"}
[04-Jun-2023 14:22:50 Europe/Berlin] {"level":"trace","message":"[707e13-036e-9341-153b-a422467ed87e98/f208f6-202c-604d-c7f5-3c008c037d347f/plain/playerlog] <127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:11210> MCBP send, opaque=3,  80 21 00 0c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 48 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00","source":{"file":"C:\\php-sdk\\php-dev\\vs17\\x64\\modules\\couchbase-php-client\\src\\deps\\couchbase-cxx-client\\core\\io\\mcbp_session.cxx","func":"couchbase::core::io::mcbp_session_impl::write","line":874},"thread_id":12944,"time":"2023-06-04 14:22:50.546553"}
[04-Jun-2023 14:22:50 Europe/Berlin] {"level":"trace","message":"[707e13-036e-9341-153b-a422467ed87e98/f208f6-202c-604d-c7f5-3c008c037d347f/plain/playerlog] <127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:11210> MCBP recv, opaque=1,  81 1f 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 20 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00","source":{"file":"C:\\php-sdk\\php-dev\\vs17\\x64\\modules\\couchbase-php-client\\src\\deps\\couchbase-cxx-client\\core\\io\\mcbp_session.cxx","func":"couchbase::core::io::mcbp_session_impl::do_read::<lambda_031a81a04307852cd14ea860ca23ba23>::operator ()","line":1401},"thread_id":12944,"time":"2023-06-04 14:22:50.550114"}
[04-Jun-2023 14:22:50 Europe/Berlin] {"level":"debug","message":"[707e13-036e-9341-153b-a422467ed87e98/f208f6-202c-604d-c7f5-3c008c037d347f/plain/playerlog] <127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:11210> supported_features=[tcp_nodelay, mutation_seqno, xattr, xerror, select_bucket, snappy, json, duplex, unordered_execution, tracing, alt_request_support, sync_replication, collections, preserve_ttl, vattr, subdoc_create_as_deleted]","source":{"file":"C:\\php-sdk\\php-dev\\vs17\\x64\\modules\\couchbase-php-client\\src\\deps\\couchbase-cxx-client\\core\\io\\mcbp_session.cxx","func":"couchbase::core::io::mcbp_session_impl::bootstrap_handler::handle","line":239},"thread_id":12944,"time":"2023-06-04 14:22:50.550309"}
[04-Jun-2023 14:22:50 Europe/Berlin] {"level":"trace","message":"[707e13-036e-9341-153b-a422467ed87e98/f208f6-202c-604d-c7f5-3c008c037d347f/plain/playerlog] <127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:11210> MCBP recv, opaque=2,  18 20 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 2d 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00","source":{"file":"C:\\php-sdk\\php-dev\\vs17\\x64\\modules\\couchbase-php-client\\src\\deps\\couchbase-cxx-client\\core\\io\\mcbp_session.cxx","func":"couchbase::core::io::mcbp_session_impl::do_read::<lambda_031a81a04307852cd14ea860ca23ba23>::operator ()","line":1401},"thread_id":12944,"time":"2023-06-04 14:22:50.550335"}
[04-Jun-2023 14:22:50 Europe/Berlin] {"level":"trace","message":"[707e13-036e-9341-153b-a422467ed87e98/f208f6-202c-604d-c7f5-3c008c037d347f/plain/playerlog] <127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:11210> MCBP recv, opaque=3,  18 21 03 00 00 00 00 21 00 00 00 9e 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00","source":{"file":"C:\\php-sdk\\php-dev\\vs17\\x64\\modules\\couchbase-php-client\\src\\deps\\couchbase-cxx-client\\core\\io\\mcbp_session.cxx","func":"couchbase::core::io::mcbp_session_impl::do_read::<lambda_031a81a04307852cd14ea860ca23ba23>::operator ()","line":1401},"thread_id":12944,"time":"2023-06-04 14:22:50.551710"}
[04-Jun-2023 14:22:50 Europe/Berlin] {"level":"trace","message":"decoding attribute list [r=0x79 0x46 0x46 0x37 0x79 0x73 0x7e 0x3506752bd3a6bc73a5,s=X7pqZrmv5K+w793k96g3ruXftkO5WtChGD9AJ0h6v6laVc6s7n6ncSjRlV/cbz1Mpar1R2Y8IufYXAViAOtfKg==,i=4000]","source":{"file":"C:\\php-sdk\\php-dev\\vs17\\x64\\modules\\couchbase-php-client\\src\\deps\\couchbase-cxx-client\\core\\sasl\\scram-sha\\scram-sha.cc","func":"couchbase::core::sasl::mechanism::scram::decodeAttributeList","line":52},"thread_id":12944,"time":"2023-06-04 14:22:50.551759"}
[04-Jun-2023 14:22:50 Europe/Berlin] {"level":"trace","message":"[707e13-036e-9341-153b-a422467ed87e98/f208f6-202c-604d-c7f5-3c008c037d347f/plain/playerlog] <127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:11210> MCBP send, opaque=4,  80 22 00 0c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a7 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00","source":{"file":"C:\\php-sdk\\php-dev\\vs17\\x64\\modules\\couchbase-php-client\\src\\deps\\couchbase-cxx-client\\core\\io\\mcbp_session.cxx","func":"couchbase::core::io::mcbp_session_impl::write","line":874},"thread_id":12944,"time":"2023-06-04 14:22:50.606384"}
[04-Jun-2023 14:22:50 Europe/Berlin] {"level":"trace","message":"[707e13-036e-9341-153b-a422467ed87e98/f208f6-202c-604d-c7f5-3c008c037d347f/plain/playerlog] <127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:11210> MCBP recv, opaque=4,  18 22 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 5d 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00","source":{"file":"C:\\php-sdk\\php-dev\\vs17\\x64\\modules\\couchbase-php-client\\src\\deps\\couchbase-cxx-client\\core\\io\\mcbp_session.cxx","func":"couchbase::core::io::mcbp_session_impl::do_read::<lambda_031a81a04307852cd14ea860ca23ba23>::operator ()","line":1401},"thread_id":12944,"time":"2023-06-04 14:22:50.617751"}
[04-Jun-2023 14:22:50 Europe/Berlin] {"level":"trace","message":"[707e13-036e-9341-153b-a422467ed87e98/f208f6-202c-604d-c7f5-3c008c037d347f/plain/playerlog] <127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:11210> MCBP send, opaque=5,  80 fe 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00","source":{"file":"C:\\php-sdk\\php-dev\\vs17\\x64\\modules\\couchbase-php-client\\src\\deps\\couchbase-cxx-client\\core\\io\\mcbp_session.cxx","func":"couchbase::core::io::mcbp_session_impl::write","line":874},"thread_id":12944,"time":"2023-06-04 14:22:50.617860"}
[04-Jun-2023 14:22:50 Europe/Berlin] {"level":"trace","message":"[707e13-036e-9341-153b-a422467ed87e98/f208f6-202c-604d-c7f5-3c008c037d347f/plain/playerlog] <127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:11210> MCBP send, opaque=6,  80 89 00 09 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00","source":{"file":"C:\\php-sdk\\php-dev\\vs17\\x64\\modules\\couchbase-php-client\\src\\deps\\couchbase-cxx-client\\core\\io\\mcbp_session.cxx","func":"couchbase::core::io::mcbp_session_impl::write","line":874},"thread_id":12944,"time":"2023-06-04 14:22:50.617881"}
[04-Jun-2023 14:22:50 Europe/Berlin] {"level":"trace","message":"[707e13-036e-9341-153b-a422467ed87e98/f208f6-202c-604d-c7f5-3c008c037d347f/plain/playerlog] <127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:11210> MCBP send, opaque=7,  80 b5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00","source":{"file":"C:\\php-sdk\\php-dev\\vs17\\x64\\modules\\couchbase-php-client\\src\\deps\\couchbase-cxx-client\\core\\io\\mcbp_session.cxx","func":"couchbase::core::io::mcbp_session_impl::write","line":874},"thread_id":12944,"time":"2023-06-04 14:22:50.617892"}
[04-Jun-2023 14:22:50 Europe/Berlin] {"level":"trace","message":"[707e13-036e-9341-153b-a422467ed87e98/f208f6-202c-604d-c7f5-3c008c037d347f/plain/playerlog] <127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:11210> MCBP recv, opaque=5,  18 fe 03 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 1f 21 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00","source":{"file":"C:\\php-sdk\\php-dev\\vs17\\x64\\modules\\couchbase-php-client\\src\\deps\\couchbase-cxx-client\\core\\io\\mcbp_session.cxx","func":"couchbase::core::io::mcbp_session_impl::do_read::<lambda_031a81a04307852cd14ea860ca23ba23>::operator ()","line":1401},"thread_id":12944,"time":"2023-06-04 14:22:50.620035"}
[04-Jun-2023 14:22:50 Europe/Berlin] {"level":"trace","message":"[707e13-036e-9341-153b-a422467ed87e98/f208f6-202c-604d-c7f5-3c008c037d347f/plain/playerlog] <127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:11210> MCBP recv, opaque=6,  18 89 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00","source":{"file":"C:\\php-sdk\\php-dev\\vs17\\x64\\modules\\couchbase-php-client\\src\\deps\\couchbase-cxx-client\\core\\io\\mcbp_session.cxx","func":"couchbase::core::io::mcbp_session_impl::do_read::<lambda_031a81a04307852cd14ea860ca23ba23>::operator ()","line":1401},"thread_id":12944,"time":"2023-06-04 14:22:50.626289"}
[04-Jun-2023 14:22:50 Europe/Berlin] {"level":"debug","message":"[707e13-036e-9341-153b-a422467ed87e98/f208f6-202c-604d-c7f5-3c008c037d347f/plain/playerlog] <127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:11210> selected bucket: playerlog","source":{"file":"C:\\php-sdk\\php-dev\\vs17\\x64\\modules\\couchbase-php-client\\src\\deps\\couchbase-cxx-client\\core\\io\\mcbp_session.cxx","func":"couchbase::core::io::mcbp_session_impl::bootstrap_handler::handle","line":317},"thread_id":12944,"time":"2023-06-04 14:22:50.626374"}
[04-Jun-2023 14:22:50 Europe/Berlin] {"level":"trace","message":"[707e13-036e-9341-153b-a422467ed87e98/f208f6-202c-604d-c7f5-3c008c037d347f/plain/playerlog] <127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:11210> MCBP recv, opaque=7,  18 b5 03 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 22 23 00 00 00 07 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00","source":{"file":"C:\\php-sdk\\php-dev\\vs17\\x64\\modules\\couchbase-php-client\\src\\deps\\couchbase-cxx-client\\core\\io\\mcbp_session.cxx","func":"couchbase::core::io::mcbp_session_impl::do_read::<lambda_031a81a04307852cd14ea860ca23ba23>::operator ()","line":1401},"thread_id":12944,"time":"2023-06-04 14:22:50.627172"}
[04-Jun-2023 14:22:50 Europe/Berlin] {"level":"debug","message":"[707e13-036e-9341-153b-a422467ed87e98/playerlog] initialize configuration rev=1:564","source":{"file":"C:\\php-sdk\\php-dev\\vs17\\x64\\modules\\couchbase-php-client\\src\\deps\\couchbase-cxx-client\\core\\bucket.cxx","func":"couchbase::core::bucket_impl::update_config","line":529},"thread_id":12944,"time":"2023-06-04 14:22:50.648573"}
[04-Jun-2023 14:22:50 Europe/Berlin] {"level":"debug","message":"[707e13-036e-9341-153b-a422467ed87e98/playerlog] rev=1:564, preserve session=\"f208f6-202c-604d-c7f5-3c008c037d347f\", address=\"127.0.0.1:11210\", index=0->0","source":{"file":"C:\\php-sdk\\php-dev\\vs17\\x64\\modules\\couchbase-php-client\\src\\deps\\couchbase-cxx-client\\core\\bucket.cxx","func":"couchbase::core::bucket_impl::update_config","line":582},"thread_id":12944,"time":"2023-06-04 14:22:50.650313"}
[04-Jun-2023 14:22:50 Europe/Berlin] {"level":"trace","message":"[707e13-036e-9341-153b-a422467ed87e98/f208f6-202c-604d-c7f5-3c008c037d347f/plain/playerlog] <127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:11210> MCBP send, opaque=8,  80 b5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00","source":{"file":"C:\\php-sdk\\php-dev\\vs17\\x64\\modules\\couchbase-php-client\\src\\deps\\couchbase-cxx-client\\core\\io\\mcbp_session.cxx","func":"couchbase::core::io::mcbp_session_impl::write","line":874},"thread_id":12944,"time":"2023-06-04 14:22:50.651737"}
```

Comment: "Same problem: no error message, PHP script ends."


But that's what your code does.  I don't see any code that prints $getResult.

Comment: Can you share the expected output that you're seeing correctly on Ubuntu?